# datatable js search is not working on suppressed test

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am showing groups as comma separated in td, if the length is not greater than 35 or else I am using sub string function to suppress the groups and showing the .. after 35 character.

In this case the search Is not working properly.
Example
Groups : User Administration, Dashboard Administration , request Administration ,User Coordinator , Scheduler, Planner

IN this case if I search for planner, the row is not getting filtered

```
data: 'RelatedGroups',
            'bSearchable': true,                
            "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                if (row.UserName.indexOf('<input') >= 0) {
                    return data;
                }
                else {
                    return '<span  title="' + data + '" id="groupEx' + row.User_Id + '">' + data.substring(0, 35) + (data.length > 35 ? '...' : '') + '</span><span id=groupExAlert' + row.User_Id +'></span>';
                }

            }
```

Thanks for your help in adance

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding hidden column.

Comment: It would be helpful to expand on this.